# OrientDB can full fill requirement of Solr or ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch, solr, lucene, orientdb

I have just started working on OrientDB, with OrientDB for search engine which tool we have to use **Solr** or **ElasticSearch** (driver compatibility). I also read somewhere that orientdb is giving Lucene Search itself if we define the index is different type. So if this is true then what about speed because **Solr** and **Elasticsearch ** serving data from primary memory.

Please suggest can OrientDB's internal functionality full fill search requirement so we use this instead of Solr or ElasticSearch.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm the maintainer of the full text and spatial indexes of OrientDB.

First of all, here's the link to the documentation, just to have an overview:

http://orientdb.com/docs/last/Full-Text-Index.html

What do we offer? 
We enable to define an index on one or more property of a Class (e.g. a Table) that uses Lucene as engine. This allow to perform queries where the full Lucene grammar could be used:

```
SELECT from Person WHERE Description LUCENE "progra* +senior -ruby"
```

You can configure analyzers and stopwords, but for sure we cannot provide the same set of features  ES or SOLR are able to.

We are improving that component for the next 3.0: more like this, highlighting, query parser configuration at query time, custom analyzer configuration.

These will improve the user experience, allowing to explore the graph in a completely different way.

In my opinion, if your main target is search, ES or SOLR fit best: they are full of features about text!

On the other end, if you need a database to store data with strong relationships and would like to provide full text search done right (based on lucene) and even spatial search, OrientDB can help you.

Comment: Franchini Thanks, So can you please share some link of example of solr and ES integration with Orientdb, also please suggest which one is best with OrientDB solr or ES.

Comment: AFAIK, there's only a "tentative" to integrate OrientDB to ES, but it didn't work.BTW, which is the best? It Depends on your use case. The first criteria that come to my mind could be: more focused on search capabilities, go to ES; more focused on relationships, go for ODB. But it is your use case and your data. And, at least, what is your knowledge in the information retrieval field.

Comment: In orientdb full text search whats about the data storing, means data stores in primary memory or secondary memory. it will directly impact on the speed.

Comment: I really don't understand your claim, I'm sorry. Do  you have numbers? Did you make some load tests? The power of OrientDB is to provide a single datastore where you can query using graph semantics AND full text. If you need a very specialized search engine AND the graph capabilities of ODB, the best way IMHO is to work in the classical "polyglot persistence" arcitecture: you store and query your data on different datastores inside your application.

Comment: Hello @RobertoFranchini - thx for answer - it seems #orientdb has nice fulltext search - I want use #orientdb because of relations I needed that now - also I needed all #elasticsearch fulltext engine - Q can you help me with some advice how can I connect them so my app can powerfully search inside blob text and use powerfull graph relations? 

Comment: @BGBruno, I'm no more the maintainer of the module, nor part of the ODB team, but if I understand your needs, the only way to go polyglot is to manage all at the application level: insert data  two times, one in orient and one in ES. Query could be performed in two ways: starting from ES using  full-text queries or SQL on orientdb. But it is all up to you how to integrate the two datastores.

Comment: @RobertoFranchini thx - that was exactly my result from my design architecture. Have a nice day. 

Comment: @RobertoFranchini, Thanks, is it possible to load elastic data to OrientDB?

Comment: @hanzgs: write your own importer. Elastic (lucene) is mainly a denormalized flat data store, while OrientDB is a graph. You only now how to normalize your data model to be stored inside a graph